# add strings without using builtin library function, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: c++

The resultnum value of this function is "01" if i try to add two strings x and y with values "0" "1". If i tried using resultnum.find_first_of("0")  it returns position as -1 instead of 0 .... i just want to get rid of that leading zero and i am unable to get rid of it... Maybe i am doing some silly mistake but please help me identify why it is returning -1 for position of 0 in result.

```
string addStrings(string num1, string num2) {

    char carry = {0},x={0},y={0},z={0};
    std::string resultnum;

    long loopUnitl=std::max(num1.size(),num2.size());
    long maxSize = loopUnitl+1;
    resultnum.reserve(maxSize);
    std::string::reverse_iterator rnum1_it=num1.rbegin();
    std::string::reverse_iterator rnum2_it=num2.rbegin();

   while(loopUnitl) 
   {

        if(rnum1_it != num1.rend())
        {
            x = *rnum1_it;
            rnum1_it++;
        }
        else
        {
            x = '0';                
        }
        if(rnum2_it != num2.rend())
        { 
            y = *rnum2_it;
            rnum2_it++;
        }
        else
            y = '0';

        z = (x -'0') + (y - '0') + carry;

       if (z > 9) 
        {

            carry = 1; 
            z -= 10;
        }
        else
        {
            carry = 0; //Else no carry was generated               
        }

        resultnum[loopUnitl] = (z+'0');
        loopUnitl=loopUnitl-1;
       if(loopUnitl==0)  
       {              
          resultnum[loopUnitl] = carry+'0';
          resultnum[maxSize]='\0';

       }

}
     return resultnum;
}
```

Comment: I'm not real clear on what you're asking. You're trying to add two strings, "0" and "1", and you want the resulting string to just be "1"? What are you _really_ trying to do, because this feels like an XY problem.

Comment: i am adding two strings and want result to be " 1" but my result is "01" because of the following line, resultnum[loopUnitl] = carry+'0';

Comment: this works good if i add string with value "99" and "1" where i get result = 100

Comment: so i try to just extract substr from 1 to length of the string and ignore first char which is zero but then that doesnt work, i get result as empty string if i try to get the substring resultnum.substr(1,resultnum.size()) ....  and if i do find_first_of("0") the result is -1 instead of 0 . Why does find_first_of("0") return -1 instead of 0?

Comment: @GirijaRam why are you building a string of digits at all? Why not do your work using normal integer arithmetic instead, and then convert the final integer result to a string when you are done? Converting an integer to a string ignores leading zeros.

Comment: Remy actually the requirement for getting the result was "You must not use any built-in BigInteger library or convert the inputs to integer directly" so i tried building string of digits .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You need to use `resultnum.resize()` instead of `resultnum.reserve()`.

Your use of `operator[]` to insert chars into `resultnum` is **undefined behavior**, because the valid range for accessing characters is `[0, size())`, not `[0, capacity())` (had you used the `at()` method instead of `operator[]`, your code would have raised exceptions warning you about indexes being out of range).

Alternatively, if you want to keep using `reserve()`, you should use the `insert()` method to add characters to the front of the string on each loop iteration, instead of using `operator[]`.

A string's `size()` and `capacity()` are two different things. The `capacity()` is how much memory the string has physically allocated to hold characters, but the `size()` is how many of those characters are actually valid data.  Operations like searching act on `size()`, not `capacity()`.

Since the string's `size()` is never > 0, that is why `find_first_of()` returns -1.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your suggestions and reply. I did change the above code to not use [] operator and just added to the string and finally reversed the string and now code works perfectly.I am so thankful to you :) .

```
   string addStrings(string num1, string num2) {

    char carry = {0};
    std::string resultnum;


    char x={0},y={0};
    char z={0};


    long loopUnitl=std::max(num1.size(),num2.size());
    long maxSize = loopUnitl+1;
    resultnum ="";
    std::string::reverse_iterator rnum1_it=num1.rbegin();
    std::string::reverse_iterator rnum2_it=num2.rbegin();


   while(loopUnitl) 
   {

        if(rnum1_it != num1.rend())
        {
            x = *rnum1_it;
            rnum1_it++;
        }
        else
        {
            x = '0';

        }
        if(rnum2_it != num2.rend())
        { 
            y = *rnum2_it;
            rnum2_it++;
        }
        else
            y = '0';

        z = (x -'0') + (y - '0') + carry;

       if (z > 9) 
        {

            carry = 1; 
            z -= 10;  

        }
        else
        {
            carry = 0; //Else no carry was generated

        }

        resultnum += (z+'0');
        loopUnitl=loopUnitl-1;
       if(loopUnitl==0)  
       {  
           if(carry)
           resultnum += (carry+'0');

       }

}
    std::reverse(resultnum.begin(),resultnum.end());
     return resultnum;
}
```